# Is there any error in this code and why it does not save Data in Database?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am just newbie to Expression language(el).

This is the code.

Before applying condition it was working correctly. Is there any error in Condition.

Non of My Parameter was empty....

I also check and instead of && and then it gives exception faild to parse EL Expression

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.firstName && not empty param.lastName && 
        not empty param.fatherName && not empty param.gender && not empty param.day &&
        not empty param.month && not empty param.year && 
        not empty param.classNo && not empty param.address} ">

<fmt:parseDate var="date" value="${param.day}-${param.month}-${param.year}" type="DATE"  
pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />

<sql:update dataSource="${StdData }" scope="page" var="result">

INSERT INTO students(FirstName,LastName,FatherName,Gender,DateOfBirth,Class,Address)  
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
<sql:param value="${param.firstName}" />

<sql:param value="${param.lastName}" />

<sql:param value="${param.fatherName}" />

<sql:param value="${param.gender}"></sql:param>

<sql:param value="${date}" />

<sql:param value="${param.classNo}" />

<sql:param value="${param.address}" />

</sql:update>


</c:if>
```

I am just wondering why this code prints all parameters while the above code do not save data to database and also if i print data there it does not show on page.

```
    <c:if test="${not empty param.firstName && not empty param.lastName && 
        not empty param.fatherName && not empty param.gender && not empty param.day &&
        not empty param.month && not empty param.year && 
        not empty param.classNo && not empty param.address}">

    <c:out value="${param.firstName}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.lastName}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.fatherName}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.gender}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.day}/"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.month}/"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.year}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.classNo}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${param.address}"></c:out>
</c:if>
```

Comment: is one of your params empty?

Comment: No All params have values

Comment: which version JSTL you have in classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Not Empty is equivalent to != null if I remember correctly. Since you're checking request parameters, wouldn't they technically have a value of "" instead of null?

I'd post this as a comment if I had 50 reputation :p

EDIT: Heres a link to the Oracle EL guide for reference.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Comment: Yeah i know they have value of "" but i have given all parameters still it does not save data to database.